# How to check all parents of the div in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a code

```
  <div id="parent">
    <div>  
      <div id="child">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

How i can to check - is there `id="child"` have a parent with `id="parent"` ?

Comment: Is This $('div#parent div#child').length, you are looking for, this will display the length if found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($("#child").closest("#parent").length) {
  // Luke, I'm your father
}
```

These should also do:

```
if($("#parent #child").length) {
  // Noooooooo!
}
if($("#parent").find("#child").length) {
  // May the force be with you
}
if($("#parent:has(#child)").length) {
  // Very powerful jQuery selector has become
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#child').closest('#parent').length){
  // yes... child is inside parent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#child').closest('#parent').length > 0) {
    // child is inside parent
}
```

You check if the child has any ancestors. You can read more about the `.closest()` function here: [jQuery docs .closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#child').parents('#parent').length > 0)
{
//true
}
```